# pandas conditional selection when counts are equal

Tags: python, pandas

Following data set represent purchase behavior:

```
user_id, product_code, bought_date, time_spent, store_id, product_type, refurbished, unqiue_visit_id
001, e.12, 20120102, 104, 101, computer, yes, 1010
002, e.24, 20120201, 100, 101, infant-dress, no, 2001
003, s.32, 20130302, 230, 101, shoes, no, 2121
004, y.23, 20130404, 212, 103, computer, yes, 2422
005, s.43, 20130803, 104, 101, laptop, yes, 2342
001, a.12, 20120102, 104, 101, computer, yes, 1011
002, b.24, 20120201, 100, 101, infant-dress, no, 2001
003, c.32, 20130302, 230, 101, shoes, no, 2122
004, e.23, 20130404, 212, 103, computer, yes, 2424
005, f.43, 20130803, 104, 101, laptop, yes, 2340
001, g.12, 20120102, 104, 101, computer, yes, 1013
002, h.24, 20120201, 100, 101, infant-dress, no, 2031
003, l.32, 20130302, 230, 101, shoes, no, 2000
004, m.23, 20130404, 212, 103, computer, yes, 1422
005, d.43, 20130803, 104, 101, laptop, yes, 1142
001, d.12, 20120102, 104, 101, desk, yes, 1110
002, f.24, 20120201, 100, 101, glass, no, 1111
003, n.32, 20130302, 230, 101, liquid, no, 2021
004, t.23, 20130404, 212, 103, liquid, yes, 22
005, u.43, 20130803, 104, 101, dress, yes, 2942
001, d.12, 20120102, 104, 101, desk, yes, 1910
002, f.24, 20120201, 100, 101, glass, no, 2901
003, n.32, 20130302, 230, 101, liquid, no, 2921
004, t.23, 20130404, 212, 103, liquid, yes, 2922
005, u.43, 20130803, 104, 101, dress, yes, 2942
001, kk.12, 20120103, 105, 101, desk, yes, 410
003, n.32, 20130303, 230, 101, liquid, no, 2621
```

End goal is to assign a product type to user using following steps.

First I group by `user_id`,`product_type` and obtain number of visits (counts) the user has visited by `product_type`.

When count are equal within group (`user_id`,`product_id`) you select the product type that is recently visited by the user and assign that to the user. If visited dates are equal then we break the tie by looking at `refurbished` value `(yes > no)`.

`visit_counts = merged_visits_df.groupby(['user_id','product_type'],                                            as_index=False).agg({'unique_visits_id': 'nunique'})`

above gives the visit counts try to figure the rest of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the below does what you ask (column names are mispelled in your posted data, i kept them that way, ie 'unqiue_visit_id')

```
counts = (
    # sort by bought date
    merged_visits_df.sort_values('bought_date', ascending=False)
    # groupby desired cols
    .groupby(['user_id','product_type'],as_index=False)
    # apply desired aggregation functions
    .agg({'unqiue_visit_id': 'nunique', 'bought_date': 'first', 'refurbished': 'first'})
)
```

Then we can get the max visit counts by user_id

```
max_by_user = counts.groupby('user_id')['unqiue_visit_id'].max()
```

Finally we can filter to those items that have visits = max visits by user, sort by desired cols, and get the first.

```
result = (
    # filter to products with max visits by user
    counts[counts['user_id'].apply(max_by_user.get) == counts['unqiue_visit_id']]
    # sort bought_date descending (max on top), refurbished descending (yes above no)
    .sort_values(['bought_date', 'refurbished'], ascending=False)
    # groupby user id and select the first
    .groupby('user_id').nth(0)
)
```

---

Maybe slightly more intuitive to think about it this way:

Step 1:
Add columns you want to sort by:

```
 # initial question
 visits_df = merged_visits_df.groupby(['user_id','product_type']).agg({'unqiue_visit_id': 'nunique'}).add_suffix('_count')
 df_to_sort = merged_visits_df.merge(visits_df.reset_index())
 # follow up question
 df_to_sort['last_num'] = df_to_sort['store_id'] % 10
```

Then sort, do groupby, get first:

```
(
    df_to_sort
    .sort_values([unqiue_visit_id_count, bought_date, last_num], ascending=[False, False, True])
    .groupby(['user_id']).nth(0)
)
```

Comment: if i want to add another condition for tie break such as last digit of the store_id, whats the best way to do that?

Comment: added follow up in answer